# Sed command to print out every 1st and 14th line of a file every 46 lines

Tags: awk, sed

So parse a text file and print out line 1 and line 14, and then do nothing with lines 15-46, and then print out line 47 and line 60, etc until the end of the file. So basically every 46 lines, print out the 1st and 14th line, repeatedly for every 46 lines until EOF

Answer (score 12):

Using GNU sed's *first~step* address range extension:

```
sed -n '1~46p; 14~46p;' file
```

Answer (score 11):

Since you have `awk` in your tags, I will provide a solution with `awk`:

```
awk '(NR%46==1||NR%46==14){print}' file
```

Comment: Clear and concise - obviously `awk` is the right tool for this job :)

Comment: `awk 'NR%46==1||NR%46==14' file` suffices, since awk triggers a `{print $0}` when a true condition occurs.

Answer (score 5):

No job for POSIX `sed`:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;y/\n#/#\n/;s/\(#[^#]*\)\{12\}#\([^#]*\)\([^#]*#\)\{33\}/#\2##/g;s/\(.*\)##.*/\1/;s/##/#/g;y/\n#/#\n/'
```

Although I consider it to be nonsense using plain POSIX `sed` for such a task when other tools are better suited, I'll add an explanation, because there are useful elements here you may need in actual tasks:

- `H;1h;$!d;x` is a pattern to collect the whole file in the pattern space, which is often useful (with GNU `sed`, you can replace it by using the `-z` option). You can figure out how it works.
- `y/\n#/#\n/` exchanges the newlines with another char (in this case `#`). Do this as a workaround before and after your processing if you need expressions like "every char except newline". Again, you don't need it with GNU `sed`, as `[^\n]` is allowed there.
- That weird pattern in the `s` command matches 12+1+33=46 `#` (formerly newlines) and 45 `[^#]*`, which are the line contents. The every first line is untouched, 12 are removed, 1 preserved as `\2` and 33 removed. This is globally done. The `##` stuff is done to remove trailing lines.

Comment: An explanation of this magic incantation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Honestly? Despite that this is clearly the wrong tool? Explaining how to hammer a nail with a screwdriver?

Comment: @shadowtalker Okay, I did. There are parts to learn for real-world cases.

Comment: With POSIX `sed`, you can always do `sed -n 'p;n;n;n;n;n;...;n;p;n;n;n...;n'` with enough `n`s. POSIX seds are not required to be able to store more than 10xLINE_MAX bytes in their hold or pattern space so storing the whole input there is not a good idea.

Comment: You need a loop around all those ps and ns

Comment: @Philippos I agree Sed is the wrong tool, but you're clearly an expert Sed user, and where better to share your knowledge than StackExchange? I certainly appreciate the explanation; I'd upvote you a second time if I could.